# How to change/customize Dropbox (folder)emblem-icons?

Tags: icons, directory, dropbox, location

I already changed all emblem-icons (I found so far on my system) in:

```
/var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/images/emblems  
/usr/share/nautilus-dropbox/emblems/
```

to no avail. Rebooting the OS doesn't change the icons either. Can anyone please provide some insights or the correct directory?

[image]